# Firebase long dynamic link analytics

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

The Dynamic Links [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/create-links) states:

> If you **don't need to track click data** and you don't care if the links are long, you can manually construct Dynamic Links using URL parameters

I'd prefer to use the long URLs (easier dynamic creation) but the above docs imply I'll lose click data. The campaign parameters can still be given to this URL, and the link is still hosted at Firebase, so it's not clear to me which analytics we'll lose here. Does anyone know the full details on this statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase team responded that the UTM data is still recorded, it's just the click count which is lost in the Firebase console.